# What's wrong with my PL/SQL function?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I get error:

```
ORA-06575: Package or function GET_CONC_NAMES is in an invalid state
```

When I try to call my get_conc_names function by:

```
SELECT get_conc_names(EVENT_ID) FROM DT_EVENT_SERVICE;
```

The function itself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_conc_names( p_event_id IN dt_event_service.event_id%type ) 
  RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS 
  l_conc_names VARCHAR2(32676);  
  -- You may want a smaller variable if you know the result will be smaller 
BEGIN 
  SELECT LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, ', '),',') conc_names 
    INTO l_conc_names 
    FROM ( 
      SELECT id, name, rownumber, cnt 
        FROM (SELECT es.EVENT_ID as id
                    ,s.SERVICE_NAME as name
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by name) as rownumber
                    ,COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
                FROM DT_SERVICES s 
                     JOIN DT_EVENT_SERVICE es ON s.SERVICE_ID = es.SERVICE_ID 
               WHERE es.EVENT_ID = p_event_id ) 
             ) data 
    WHERE rownumber = cnt 
    START WITH rownumber = 1 
    CONNECT BY PRIOR rownumber = rownumber-1; 
  RETURN l_conc_names; 
END;
```

Compilation errors:

> Compilation failed,line 13 (10:58:37) PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "NAME":
>   invalid identifierCompilation failed,line 7 (10:58:37) PL/SQL: SQL
>   Statement ignored

Comment: again try to compile your function .. and if it will compile successfully .. just log off and log in again .. then your query should run without giving this type of error ..

Comment: Please show us the errors you get when you compile the function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wrong identifier is probably in the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by name)` clause.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_conc_names( p_event_id IN dt_event_service.event_id%type ) 
  RETURN VARCHAR2 
IS 
  l_conc_names VARCHAR2(32676);  
  -- You may want a smaller variable if you know the result will be smaller 
BEGIN 
  SELECT LTRIM(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, ', '),',') conc_names 
    INTO l_conc_names 
    FROM ( 
      SELECT id, name, rownumber, cnt 
        FROM (SELECT es.EVENT_ID as id
                    ,s.SERVICE_NAME as name
                    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by s.SERVICE_NAME) as rownumber
                    ,COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
                FROM DT_SERVICES s 
                     JOIN DT_EVENT_SERVICE es ON s.SERVICE_ID = es.SERVICE_ID 
               WHERE es.EVENT_ID = p_event_id ) 
             ) data 
    WHERE rownumber = cnt 
    START WITH rownumber = 1 
    CONNECT BY PRIOR rownumber = rownumber-1; 
  RETURN l_conc_names; 
END;
```

Comment: This is an issue because the columns in a `select` clause are evaluated as if they were evaluated all at the same time, not one after another.

Comment: Exactly. Column aliases in the select clause cannot be used in the where clause.